# DS18B20 and RPi Pico

Tags: ds18b20, 1-wire, micropython, pi-pico

I will be getting my Raspberry pi pico here in a few days and want to connect a DS18B20 and use MicroPython. I have a project the uses RPi zero w and Python3.9. Since obviously, the pico does not use an os, is there a way to read a 1-wire device? Or do I need to switch to a different method for reading temperature? I know that the ESP32 port has a class for it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use adafruit mycropython fork called circuitpython - https://circuitpython.org/board/raspberry_pi_pico/ and then you can use circuitpython onewire and ds18b20 libraries https://learn.adafruit.com/using-ds18b20-temperature-sensor-with-circuitpython/circuitpython

Comment: Actually, ignore that ... pico micropython has libraries you need https://github.com/raspberrypi/micropython/tree/pico/drivers/onewire

Comment: @JaromandaX, I try Steve Robillard's answer using JaromandaX's link and see what happens. Thank you and will update after this weekend and upvote both if it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use a DS18B20 with MicrPython on the Pico. All the required modules are included. The following is based on this [MicroPython tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/micropython-ds18b20-esp32-esp8266/) from Random Nerd Tutorials.

**Hardware**

To wire the sensor to your Pico:

- Connect the sensor's ground to one of the ground pins on the Pico.
- Connect the sensor's VCC pin to the Pico's 3.3V(out) pin.
- Connect the Sensor's  data pin to the Pico's GPIO4

[image: Raspberry Pi Pico Pinout]

**Software**

1. Create a new file in Thonny.
2. Paste the following code into your new file:

```
    import machine, onewire, ds18x20, time
    
    ds_pin = machine.Pin(4)
    ds_sensor = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(ds_pin))
    
    roms = ds_sensor.scan()
    print('Found DS devices: ', roms)
    
    while True:
      ds_sensor.convert_temp()
      time.sleep_ms(750)
      for rom in roms:
        print(rom)
        print(ds_sensor.read_temp(rom))
      time.sleep(5)
```

3. Save the file to your pico as ds18b20.py.
4. Click the run button in Thonny and you should see temperature readings appear in Thonny's shell every 5 seconds.

Comment: I will try this when my pico arrives at the end of this week. The tutorial says that the onewire library is from the esp32 port of micropython though

Comment: onewire is onewire @KelbyCriswell - most code for microcontrollers comes from other code :p

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just want sure if the pico supports I swore communication. I will find out this weekend.

Comment: It works I wouldn't have posted had I not tried it.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, Sorry, I did not mean to offend. In other communities, I have seen people post things that they have not verified. I was just concerned since the Pico uPython sdk says nothing about builtins. There was a delay in customs for my Pico so it will be tonight that I test it all out. Thank you again.

Comment: Tested and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: @SteveRobillard  Many thanks - this is really useful.  I've connected this up as described and it works well reading two sensors.  Being new to this, one thing I don't understand: in the Random Nerd tutorial you link to, there is a resistor on the data pin.  Why is that not needed with pico?

Comment: @Aidan It won't hurt to add it - it is cheap insurance. I may have omitted it because I was using a breakout board, but that was a while ago.

Comment: This did not fully solve my problem. The code would not hit a runtime failure, however my sensor was still not recognized/found. For anyone else who was struggling, the 4.7k resistor connecting the COM line to the 3.3v power was required for me when just using a pi-pico, breadboard and sensor.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, but there's no error checking.  Remove the sensor lead ( or put it in the wrong GPIO slot ) and you get a python error in convert temp.  I'd rather print a warning like "Plug in the sensor, dummy!" and then stop before it gets to that point.